# Prove $T' = 0$ if and only if $T=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-maps

**Theorem.** Given that $W$ is finite-dimensional and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$. then $T'=0$ if and only if $T=0$.

I’m having trouble proving $T=0$ if $T' = 0$. I see a counter example to this. From hypothesis $T'=0$ so equivalently given any linear functional $\psi \in W', T'(\psi)= \psi \circ T=0$. Then $T$ can be non zero when $\psi$ is a zero map i.e. all values in $W$ are mapped to $0$. Then $T$ does not have to be $0$. Could someone please explain what am I missing here? Thank you!

Comment: $T' (\psi) = 0$ must hold for _all_ $\psi \in W'$, not just $\psi = 0$.

Comment: What is $T'$? Do you mean the adjoint $T':W'\to V'$ given by $T'(\phi)(x)=\phi(Tx)$ for all $\phi\in W'$ ?

Answer (score 1):

To do that, take any $x\in V$. If $T'=0$ then you have $T'(\phi)=\phi\circ T=0$ for all $\phi\in W'$.  Then you have $\phi(Tx)=0$ for all $\phi\in W'$.

So, fix a basis $e_{1},...,e_{m}$ of $W$ and the corresponding dual basis $E_{1},...,E_{m}$ of $W'$. So if $Tx=\sum_{k=1}^{m}c_{k}e_{k}$, then as $E_{k}(Tx)=0$, you have $c_{k}=0$ for each $k$.

This proves that $Tx=0$. Then as $x$ was arbitrary in $V$, you have that $Tx=0$ for all $x$ and hence $T=0$.

PS: This is also true in infinite dimensional normed spaces but it requires something called the Hahn-Banach Theorem to prove it rigorously.